# Angular Material - md-radio-group not rendering as expecting safari

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a multi row of radio buttons through a ng-repeat. In Safari the radio buttons render overlapping each other. A photo of the behaviour below:
[image: Safari behaviour]

In Chrome it renders as expected photo below.
[[image: Chrome Behaviour[2]]

What I am doing wrong? Code below:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in multi.multiChoice" layout="column" layout-align='start start' ng-if="multi.viewFn()">
  <div class='multi-button' flex='70' md-theme="altTheme">
    <md-radio-group class='md-primary' ng-model="multi.content.value" >
        <div flex layout='row' layout-padding layout-align="start center"  ng-style="{'background-color':multi.checkFn('BG',item.value),'color':multi.checkFn('FONT',item.value)}">          
          <md-radio-button flex ng-value="item.value">
            {{item.value}}
          </md-radio-button>
        </div>
        <span </span>
    </md-radio-group>        
  </div>      
</div>
<md-button  class="md-raised md-warn" aria-label="Edit" ng-click="multi.content.value=null" ng-if="multi.viewFn()">
      Clear
</md-button> 
<label ng-if="!multi.viewFn()">{{multi.content.value}}</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `ng-repeat` from the outermost `div` to the parent `div` of the `md-radio-button` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/oLBKge?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-radio-group class='md-primary' ng-model="multi.content.value" >
    <div flex layout='row' layout-padding layout-align="start center"  ng-style="{'background-color':multi.checkFn('BG',item.value),'color':multi.checkFn('FONT',item.value)}"  ng-repeat="item in multi.multiChoice">          
      <md-radio-button flex ng-value="item.value">{{item.value}}</md-radio-button>
    </div>
  </md-radio-group>        
  <md-button  class="md-raised md-warn" aria-label="Edit" ng-click="multi.content.value=null">
    Clear
  </md-button> 
  <label>{{multi.content.value}}</label>
</div>
```

JS

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.multi = {
    multiChoice: [
      {value: "Tom Cruise"},
      {value: "Danny De Vito"},
      {value: "Hugh jackman"}
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I also found for the some reason it did not like the layout='column' in the outer most div.